# Python error when using MEGAHIT assembler on cygwin

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin, bioinformatics

I have recently downloaded Megahit(https://github.com/voutcn/megahit) and would like to have a try on it.

I have simply enter the following command:

> ./megahit -r ./example/refExample.fa --k-max 99 --k-min 11

Which I would try to use the example given by Megahit with k-mer of maximum 99 and minimum of 11 to see if it works.
However, the returns is as follow:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "./megahit", line 1143, in "<"module>
>     sys.exit(main())
>
> File "./megahit", line 1067, in main 
>      get_version()
>
> File "./megahit", line 526, in
>   get_version
>
> stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].rstrip().decode('utf-8'))
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

The code from the script is as follow:

```
def get_version():
global megahit_version_str
global usage_message
global max_k_allowed
megahit_version_str = "MEGAHIT " + \
                      subprocess.Popen([opt.bin_dir + "megahit_asm_core", "dumpversion"],
                                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].rstrip().decode('utf-8')

max_k_allowed = int(subprocess.Popen([opt.bin_dir + "megahit_asm_core", "kmax"],
                                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].rstrip().decode('utf-8'))

usage_message = usage_message % (max_k_allowed, max_k_allowed, max_k_allowed)
```

The system base I am using is Window 64bit with cygwin64.
I am having python version 2.7.13 from cygwin.

I have searched on google and else where and they mostly pointed out that I might have defined the variable wrongly, so I did try to change to use `Float`, but it does not work too.

I am not familiar to python, do anyone else have the same experience on this when using Megahit?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: downloaded which version ? How did you installed it ?

Comment: Note that if you are going to use more bioinformatics programs, it could save you lots of trouble when installing them if you worked on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Following instructions at:
https://github.com/voutcn/megahit
on a cygwin 64 bit installation

```
git clone https://github.com/voutcn/megahit.git
cd megahit
make
```

Make will fail with `fileno not in scope`; this is due to `-std=c++0x` in the CXXFLAGS. You need to remove it:

```
sed -i -e "s/-std=c++0x//" Makefile
make
```

After that the example can be run and

```
 $ ./megahit -m 1000000000 -r ./example/refExample.fa --k-max 99 --k-min 15
MEGAHIT v1.1.1-2-g02102e1
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:44 2017] Start assembly. Number of CPU threads 4 ---
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:44 2017] Available memory: 0, used: 1000000000
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:44 2017] Converting reads to binaries ---
    [read_lib_functions-inl.h  : 209]     Lib 0 (./example/refExample.fa): se, 1 reads, 1232 max length
    [utils.h                   : 126]     Real: 0.2340  user: 0.1090    sys: 0.0150     maxrss: 4760
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:45 2017] k list: 15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95,99 ---
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:45 2017] Extracting solid (k+1)-mers for k = 15 ---
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:46 2017] Building graph for k = 15 ---
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:47 2017] Assembling contigs from SdBG for k = 15 ---
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:47 2017] Local assembling k = 15 ---
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:47 2017] Extracting iterative edges from k = 15 to 25 ---
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:48 2017] Merging to output final contigs ---
--- [STAT] 1 contigs, total 570 bp, min 570 bp, max 570 bp, avg 570 bp, N50 570 bp
--- [Sat Jul 15 12:07:49 2017] ALL DONE. Time elapsed: 4.711208 seconds ---
```

For `k`, the value 11 does not work as `all must be odd, in the range 15-255`  while `-m` is needed as `megahit` is unable to detect the available memory, I did not investigated in the matter

Comment: Thanks Mat!
I am sorry for the late reply... Have been busy for another thing these days...
So I have tried your method but after I remove the -std=c++0x, this time, cygwin claims that ‘static_assert’ was not declared in this scope and failed to complete the make process ...

Comment: I used the gcc-6.3.0-2 compiler. https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2017-06/msg00079.html